# handle rangeSelector button when it is out of range of xaxis of data series

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Minimum range of x-axis of data series is 5/15/2006 
I send the current max value of x-axis of display chart is 5/24/2011 and zoom button is selected as past 7 days, then if I select the zoom button past 30 days, because it is out of the range of x-axis, so I want it to make this select invalid and keep the old past 7 days zoom button and the range of display chart doesn't change.

how to do this?

Here is the JS code:

```
var end = 1148428800000;
var rowcount;

$(function () {
    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function (data) {

        // Create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
            navigator: {
                enabled: false
            },
            scrollbar: {
                enabled: false
            },

            rangeSelector: {
                inputEnabled: false,
                selected: 0,
                buttonTheme: {
                    width: null
                },
                buttons: [{
                    type: 'day',
                    count: 6,
                    text: 'past 7 days'
                }, {
                    type: 'day',
                    count: 14,
                    text: 'past 15 days'
                }, {
                    type: 'day',
                    count: 29,
                    text: 'past 30 days'
                }]
            },

            xAxis: {
                max: end,
                type: 'datetime',
                minTickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                events: {
                    setExtremes: function (e) {
                        if (typeof (e.rangeSelectorButton) !== 'undefined') {
                            rowcount = e.rangeSelectorButton.count;
                        }
                    }
                }
            },

            title: {
                text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
                data: data,
                marker: {
                    enabled: true,
                    radius: 3
                },
                shadow: true,
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }]
        });
    });

});
```

Here is the [[Jsfiddle]](http://jsfiddle.net/Jennysayhello/DE9Rs/1/)

Comment: Could you provide some more details. A jsFiddle of what you already have, a screenshot.

It seams to me that you'll have to do some calculations in javascript

Comment: updated the jsfiddle code and the problem description

Comment: At this time I don't have much time to investigate this. But I think your end time needs to be: var end = 1306195200000;

Comment: you don't get the question. The end is set and doesn't change.

Comment: You can wrap default click button function (on rangeselector) by API. http://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts (the function is Highcharts.RangeSelector.prototype.clickButton.