# how to make the rangeselector button invalid to choose

Tags: highcharts

If the current dataset is only a week long, then all the default rangeselector buttons are invalid to choose. 
Here I have a dataset is between 3 years from 2010/12/1 to 2014/4/20, but I will set the max value of x-axis of display chart is 2012/2/3. using the code:

```
xAxis: {
       max: 1328256000
}
```

But the all the default buttons are valid to select. But from this max value 2012/2/3 of display chart, it cannot show the previous years chart. I want to set the 1 year button invalid to select when time range is smaller than 1 year.

Can we achieve this?

Comment: If you could show jsFiddle, it would be better. Anyway, your max value is incorrect. should be: `1328256000000` - in JS we use timestamp in ms.

Comment: Is that duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24573487/handle-rangeselector-button-when-it-is-out-of-range-of-xaxis-of-data-series ?